# How to write a css/xpath for dynamically changing element?

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I am using beautiful soup and below is my selector to scrape href.

```
html = '''      <a data-testid="Link" class="sc-pciXn eUevWj JobTile___StyledJobLink-sc- 
                 1nulpkp-0 gkKKqP JobTile___StyledJobLink-sc-1nulpkp-0 gkKKqP" 
                  href="https://join.com/companies/talpasolutions/4978529-project-customer- 
                   success-manager-heavy-industries-d-f-m">'''

soup = beautifulsoup(HTML , "lxml")

jobs = soup.find_all( "a" ,class_= "sc-pciXn eUevWj JobTile___StyledJobLink-sc-1nulpkp-0 
                                gkKKqP JobTile___StyledJobLink-sc-1nulpkp-0 gkKKqP")

for job in jobs:
    job_url = job.get("href")
```

**I am using find_all because there is a total of 3 elements with hrefs.**

**Above method is working but the website keeps changing the classes on a daily basis. I need a different way to design CSS/XPath**

Comment: Can you please add more context? Is there always `JobTile_...` in the `class=`?

Comment: No , Every class changes

Comment: I think they purposely done that to restrict scraping data

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: https://join.com/companies/talpasolutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://join.com/companies/talpasolutions"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "lxml")

for a in soup.select("a:has(h3)"):
    print(a.get("href"))
```

Prints:

```
https://join.com/companies/talpasolutions/4978529-project-customer-success-manager-heavy-industries-d-f-m
https://join.com/companies/talpasolutions/4925936-senior-data-engineer-d-f-m
https://join.com/companies/talpasolutions/4926107-senior-data-scientist-d-f-m
```

Comment: Thanks, apparently it was not so difficult. It only required some knowledge of constructing selectors. Thanks again.